# Reading from MongoDB using PySpark Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pyspark

I am new to Spark (PySpark) and MongoDB.

I am very much learning as I go, but in my Python code, I want to connect to a MongoDB collection and read data from this collection.

The MongoDB is located on a local VM - http://localhost:27017

I am struggling to find out how to connect to it. I have tried the below, but it seems to just be returning empty data.

```
    client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    db = client['Raw_Data']
    collection = db['Raw_Data_Collection']

    import pyspark
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate();
    df = pyspark.read.format("mongodb://localhost").load()

    df = pyspark.read.format("mongo").option(client, "mongodb://localhost/Raw_Data.Raw_Data_Collection").load()
    
    if(df.count > 0):
        print("Not empty")
        df.show()
```

I am a complete novice so the above code might be way out!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I read & write to Mongo from Spark,

## Write to Cosmos DB

CONNECTION_STRING = "mongodb://cosmosdb-the-entire-uri"
df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("Database", "abc").option("uri", CONNECTION_STRING).option("Collection", "abc2").save()

## Read from Cosmos DB

df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("Database", "abc").option("Collection", "abc2").option("uri", CONNECTION_STRING).load()

Hope this helps.